# How to decode a JSON-encoded column in awk?

Tags: json, shell, unix, awk

Say I have a tab delimited file.  In it, I have a data column that is encoded in JSON. Is there a way to decode the JSON data and use it in a meaningful way?  Ideally, the method would decode the JSON data into awk's hash table / array. Alternatively, Something like Hive's [get_json_object](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-getjsonobject) will also work as well.

Comment: IMO this might be a good time to consider moving away from `awk` to a more general-purpose language.

Comment: I suspect awk experts are looking at this question and wondering what the heck JSON is while JSON experts are looking at it and wondering what the heck awk is. Maybe an exaggeration but hopefully you get the point that it's unlikely anyone reading this is an expert in both areas. If you'd like input from an awk expert i how to decode JSON, post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments! Let me just say this: please keep in mind that I have my own reason for using awk this way. I know there are other ways to parse JSON. Before you critique whether or not this should be done in awk, I simply ask you to understand the focus of the question is on how, not why. So, if you do decide to answer the question, please keep your focus on "how" whenever possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Awk does not have any facility for decoding JSON.  It's time to move to a more general-purpose programming language, like Perl or Python or Ruby, all of which have modules for dealing with both JSON and column-delimited text.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Don't do it.

To elaborate on the common opinion: Awk has functions (including recursive), associative arrays, many in-built string functions with regex support. So, yes, it is possible to write an Awk program for this. Can this be done in a one-liner, which is what Awk is mostly used for? Very unlikely.

e.g. Consider this tiny JSON "object": `{a: b, c: d}` as the only field.

This could be your Awk program:

```
echo {a: b, c: d} | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}
     {sub("{", "", $1); sub("}", "", $1); split($1, array, ", ");
         for (key in array) {
             split(array[key], array2, ": ");
             dict[array2[1]] = array2[2];
         }
     }
     END {for (key in dict) print key, dict[key]}'
```

This will finally give you a "dict" with keys "a" and "b", and values "c" and "d". Hard to build on, and harder to maintain and modify. Save yourself the trouble. There are many neater alternatives. e.g. [Python JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).